# Bash, скрипт, который удаляет все файлы, кроме cpp

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Выдает ошибку во второй строке, хотя в терминале та же команда работает нормально. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, что не так.
Вот сам скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo удалить файлы \: `find !(*.cpp) -maxdepth 0` \?
read -n 1 x

while( [ "$x" -ne "y" && "$x" -ne "n" ] )
do
if [[ "$x" -eq "y" ]]
then 
rm `find !(*.cpp) -maxdepth 0`
else if [[ "$x" -ne "n" ]]
then
echo  введён неверный символ, повторите ввод
read -n 1 x
if
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то все сложно , можно сделать проше

```
find . -type f | sed "/\.cpp/d" | xargs rm -f
```

Это просто удалить все файлы без подтверждения

Comment: Меньше пайпов, больше профита: `find <path> -type f ! -name '*.cpp' -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: Да так более красиво

Comment: Спасибо, но все-таки хотелось бы узнать в чем ошибка в моем скрипте, просто я только начал изучать баш и мне интересно разобраться с его условными операторами и циклами

Comment: find !(*.cpp) -maxdepth 0  . более првильно   find .  ! -name "*.cpp" -maxdepth 0 .

Comment: Спасибо, не могли бы вы подсказать, что значат точки в данном случае?

Comment: find <от куда искать> точка в текушем каталоге  , можно поставь find /home/user будет искать в кталоге /home/user

Comment: @Fexolm когда пишите про ошибку, добавляйте конкретный вывод ошибки.